# Executing task after condition is met in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

Let's assume we have:

```
bool condition = false;
```

Now I want to start a new task:

```
new Task(() => 
{
    Do something as soon as condition == true;

}).Start();
```

The condition will be changed to true by another Thread/Task after sometime

How can I do that please?

Edit:

I have a program for backuping one folder, to another. I can set multiple folders (for axample A -> B, C -> D). Than I start the program and it starts copying files.

But when I add new folder (E -> F) when the program is already running, I must start it manually again (after it finishes doing A -> B and C -> D) for making him do E -> F.

I want it, when adding a new folder, start automatically again after current job is done, to do the new one.

Comment: There are way too many different ways to do this. Your question is far too broad. You need to do some research and examine what your options are. Post a question if you need some _specific_ help. Maybe you need to await a `TaskCompletionSource`'s task, maybe you need to subscribe to `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged`, maybe you just need to add code to a property setter, etc. Please narrow the question considerably, so that it's clear what _single_ implementation would be most suitable for your case.

Comment: Actually now that I have said one of the answers I think that it's not too broad but rather unclear of what you are asking. Please edit the question and tell us what exactly are you after the scenario is unclear for me.

Comment: See [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) you can use its events for what you want. Be wary of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/208223).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you right, you are looking for something like this:

```
  //TODO: do not forget to dispose m_Condition 
  ManualResetEventSlim m_Condition = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);

  public bool Condition {
    get {
      return m_Condition.IsSet;  
    }
    set {
      if (value) 
        m_Condition.Set();
      else
        m_Condition.Reset();
    }
  } 

  ...

  Task myTask = Task.Run(() => {
    m_Condition.Wait();

    //TODO: put relevant code here
  });
```

The task will start as soon as `Condition` is switched into `true`:

```
  Condition = true; // this unlock myTask
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to do such a thing but the easiest one might be to use a property:

```
bool condition = false;

bool Condition
{
    get { return condition; }
    set
    {
        if(!condition  value)
        {
            //Now condition has changed from false to true
            //Do what you want here
        }
        condition = value;
    }
}
```

**--Edit--**

I found out that your question was to when change from false to true so I edited the set part a little bit

Comment: Well, This came to my mind, but the "my work" should not be done every time, but only after I call it.

Comment: `bool volatile condition = false;`  `volatile` to prevent optimization and ensure that condition is re-read