# Task wait problem while waiting a request

Tags: c#, task

I am new to C# and I'm trying to understand the Task logic.

I wait for a response from a device which opens a led bulb. I want to wait until the light bulb flag turns true, then serialize it.

1) I checked many questions here, most of them use Task array but I have only one task. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43361829/executing-task-after-condition-is-met-in-c-sharp#) question and applied the same logic, however, my Task does nothing.

2) On top that, I put breakpoints near:
`m_Condition.Set();` and  `m_Condition.Set();`, seems like the compiler does not even see Task, they have no value. However, **led is ON** (means light_flag is true) but when I print before and after serialize `light_flag` looks false. I can not catch the moment when it is true.

3) Also, I tried to create a thread instead of Task but I couldn't catch the value when it becomes true.

I am stuck can you please show me the way?

```
    ManualResetEventSlim m_Condition = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);

    public bool Condition {
        get {
            return m_Condition.IsSet;
        }
        set {
            if (!obj.light_flag) m_Condition.Set();
            else m_Condition.Reset();
        }
    }

    private void chk_Test1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        if (chk_Test1.Checked == true) SendMsg("light_flag");

        Task myTask = Task.Run(() = >{
            m_Condition.Wait();

            Serialize();

        });

    }

    void Serialize() {
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.Indented);
        File.WriteAllText(path_combined, json);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with threads, I give the start of the thread before sending the message to device. So that it never miss the message(when light_flag returns true).